# In a list, is there a way to define undefined variables?

Tags: python

I have a list of variable names, if a variable doesn't exist I wish to create it and assign the value of 'Missing'.

For single values it's simply:

```
if not val1:
    val1 = 'Missing'
if not val2:
    val2 = 'Missing'
if not val3:
    val3 = 'Missing'
```

However, as soon as I create the list it'll give a "is not defined" error.

```
values = [val1, val2, val3, val4]

for value in values:
    if not value:
        value = 'Missing'
    else:
        pass
```

Is there a way to iterate through the variable names, creating and assigning the value to each (rather then repeatedly using an 'if not' value?)

Comment: `if not val` does *not* test if a variable is defined.  It tests if it is logically false.  It will fail for `False`, `0`, `0.0`, `None`, the empty string `""`, etc.  So it's not doing anything like what you think it does.

Comment: How does `if not val1` work if `val1` doesn't exist? do you mean it's `None`?

Comment: This looks like you want to use a dictionary or a list instead of a sequence of variables.

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Your program should never be in a state where it tries to work with an undefined variable. Initialize those variables with `None` or use a dictionary as @KlausD. said.

Comment: Where are those variables coming from? Probably the best way to deal with this is to ensure they're always initialized to something, even if it's just a sentinel value like your `'Missing'` strings or a constant like `None`. Generally, variable names should not be data, so don't try to treat them that way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
values = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4']

for value in values:
    if value not in dir():
        exec(f"{value} = 'Missing'")
```

But as others mentioned, it seems not a good approach.